# Is there some way to have a Java Enum effectively inherit a constructor and have a variable with a generic type?

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

My code has features (which all extend MyFeature) which can be toggled on and off globally or per-guild in a config. Some features also have 'sub-features' called addons (which all extend MyAddon) which can only be enabled if their parent feature is also enabled. Like features, each addon can be toggled on and off globally or per-guild.

Each feature which has addons available has an enum to list all the available addons, whether they're configurable and how to construct them. This is because I am using Jackson to deserialize a YAML file for me, and an enum where each value has a Constructor for the corresponding addon class is the closest I can get to deserializing a String to a class.

However, because most of the basic code for each of these features' addon enums is the same, I would like to reduce this using inheritance. Here is this 'basic code'. The dashes represent the name of each addon, which is obviously different between addons but the same within one addon

```
public enum ---Addons {
    example_addon(true, ExampleAddon.class); // Not the same between addons

    public final boolean configurable;
    public final Constructor<? extends ---Addon> handler;
    ---Addons(boolean configurable, Class<? extends ---Addon> addonHandler) {
        this.configurable = configurable;

        if (addonHandler == null) {
            handler = null;
        } else {
            Constructor<? extends ---Addon> setHandler;
            try {
                setHandler = addonHandler.getConstructor();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                MyLogger.error("Could not find constructor for addon {}",name());
                setHandler = null;
            }
            handler = setHandler;
        }
    }
}
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to inherit any of this. All enums extend Enum and manually extending Enum is not allowed so it is not possible for an enum to extend our own abstract class. But an interface wouldn't work either because interfaces can't declare a default constructor nor a variable with a generic type all an interface's fields are static. The former issue could be solved to an extent by using a default method, but because this method wouldn't be able to set the class variables either, the method would have to return these variables which would be set independently in each implementation of the interface.

Is there some way to get around these issues OR is there an alternative way I can structure my codebase so that Jackson can still deserialize Strings to a class reference (knowing that the class will inherit from MyAddon.class) without using enums?

Comment: Sounds like your use case is perfect example for Sealed Classes that were introduced in Java 16. If you are using Java 17 or above, sealed classes comes to your rescue. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/language/sealed-classes-and-interfaces.html

Comment: @GopinathRadhakrishnan Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I've seen sealed classes before and I had a look back at the docs you sent but I don't see how restricting which of my classes can extend another would help. If anything, I'm looking to unrestrict access to the Enum class